# OpenGL not making a perfect cube

Tags: c++, opengl

I am new to openGL and I am trying to learn the basics. I've created the vertices of a cube and their indices for the EBO, it supposed to be a perfect cube, that means, the same length in all sides. However I get this:
https://i.gyazo.com/1fb82be379da9b18133a0ab0da8ccbf4.png
This kind of a  rectangle, istead of a square face.

The vertices and the indices are the following:

```
    std::vector<GLfloat> _Vertices  = {
    // Positions          // Colors           // Texture Coords
                                                            //Front
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,   //0 Top Right
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,   //1 Bottom Right
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,   //2 Bottom Left
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,   //3 Top Left
                                                            //Right
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,   //4 Top left
     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,   //5 Top right
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,   //6 Bottom right
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,   //7 Buttom left
                                                            //Left
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,   //8 Top Right
    -0.5f,  0.5f,-0.5f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,   //9 Buttom Right
    -0.5f, -0.5f,-0.5f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,   //10 Buttom Leff
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,    //11 Top Left

                                                            //Top
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,   //12 Buttom Left
    -0.5f,  0.5f,-0.5f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,   //13 Top Left
     0.5f,  0.5f,-0.5f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,   //14 Top Right
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,   //15 Buttom right

                                                            //Back
     0.5f,  0.5f,-0.5f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,   //16 Top Right
     0.5f, -0.5f,-0.5f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,   //17 Bottom Right
    -0.5f, -0.5f,-0.5f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,   //18 Bottom Left
    -0.5f,  0.5f,-0.5f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,   //19 Top Left

                                                            //Buttom
    -0.5f, -0.5f,-0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,   //20 Top left
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,   //21 Top Right
     0.5f, -0.5f,-0.5f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,   //22 Buttom Right
    -0.5f, -0.5f,-0.5f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f    //23 Buttom Lrft


};






    std::vector<GLuint> Indices = {
    0, 1, 2, // Firs square
    2, 3, 0,

    4, 5, 6,
    6, 7, 4,

    8, 9, 10,
    10, 11, 8,

    12, 13, 14,
    14, 15, 12,

    16, 17, 18,
    18, 19, 16,

    20, 21, 22,
    22, 23, 20
};
```

Now, if you need a part of the code,  please ask in the comment section. Thanks.

Comment: How did you set up your projection matrix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your X and Y coordiantes range from -0.5 to 0.5 but your Z is only -0.5 to 0.0

Comment: Gee, how i missed that? Thanks, alot!